# How does the brewing potion work in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I started playing Minecraft Bedrock again after some while, because I stopped playing because of the narrator thing. The chest or crafting box or something moreover has so many questions on Arqade about potions, or codes with hacks/mods. To start off of my many questions about Minecraft, I want to know how the craft box works and how I can brew potions with it.

I see some answers with codes included, but I don't know if it's for the mod specifically, or the game itself. If so, how can I insert the code into the craft box?

---

#### Accepted Answer

A accepted answer would have details about the items that you would use, so  **make an example potion  with items.** Show the picture of the potion, such as invisibility. It will have the answer to if the code is meant for mods or not in the beginning, then add a line spacer, getting to the point. The last thing it should include is recommended ways to do this quickly.

---

Comment: the craft box? The crafting table cannot make potions. and im not sure what you mean by "codes" either, do you mean commands? and i dont think you even mentioned what mod you are talking about.

Comment: if you arent using mods, remove all the references to a mod as it could be confusing. if im understanding correctly, you want to be able to spawn in potions using commands, or do you want to create them with cheats off?

Comment: Useful image for brewing:https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/minecraft_gamepedia/images/7/7b/Minecraft_brewing_en.png/revision/latest?cb=20201124163604

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you want to know about how to brew potions. It's quite simple in fact. Here's how to brew one.

- For starters the brewing stand has five slots as shown:

[image]

The top slot is where you put your ingredients (nether wart, redstone, glowstone, ghast tear, magma cream, etc.)

The left slot is where you put blaze powder, what fuels the brewing stand. It can also be used as an ingredient but we'll go over that later.

The bottom slot is where you but the bottles. This is where you will place your water bottles and claim the newly made potions. Now lets get to brewing.

You'll need 1-3 water bottles (would recommend getting 3 because you'll get three potions from it), blaze powder to fuel the brewing stand, redstone, glowstone or gunpowder(optional if you want to boost the potion's effects, a nether wart(used to make awkward potions) and at least one ingredient listed below and what it grants:

1. **Sugar**, swiftness
2. **Rabbits foot**, leaping
3. Blaze powder, strength
4. **Glistering melon**, healing(instant health)
5. **Spider eye**, poison
6. Ghast tear, Regeneration
7. Magma cream, Fire resistance
8. Pufferfish, Water breathing
9. **Golden Carrot**, Night Vision
10. Turtle shell, Slowness & Resistance
11. Phantom Membrane, Slow falling
12. Fermented spider eye*, weakness
    *The fermented spider eye can be used without a awkward potion.

As you can see I bolded some of the ingredients. These ingredients can be corrupted by putting a fermented spider eye in the ingredients slot after brewing these certain potions. This is what the corruption will do:

1. Sugar - Slowness
2. Rabbits foot - Slowness
3. Glistering melon - harming
4. Spider eye - harming
5. Golden carrot - invisibility

Now let's actually brew the potion. First you'll need to put the water bottle into the bottom three slots. Once you do this place a nether wart in the ingredient tab(if you are brewing a potion of weakness you can skip this paragraph. It should start brewing as long as there's blaze powder in the fuel slot. Once it is brewed the bottles should be labeled "awkward potion"

Next place your selected ingredient in the ingredient slot. When you finish brewing you'll receive the corresponding potion.

Tip: If you want to increase the duration add redstone dust. If you want to increase the power add glowstone. If you want to make it a splash potion add gunpowder. Just remember you can't put glowstone and redstone in the same potion.

Congratulations! You successfully just made your first potion!

Comment: But if your'e using code then just do /give <entity>

Comment: You cannot give yourself potions using the /give command. You can give yourself the necessary water bottles, though.