# How can I give myself certain potions via commands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making an RPG server and so I'm also making shops where you use points to get items, everything is working but the potions, I tried to look up how to give potions with command block but every answer tells me to use numbers (ID for the potion) which does not work, how do I give a potion with the effects already in game with command block?

Comment: Are you sure you tried as said? Can you show some of the ways you found online? Can you also show perhaps  a bit of your game's progress?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the brewing potion work in Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/383560/how-does-the-brewing-potion-work-in-minecraft)

Comment: @loan_2314 thats not commands

Comment: @Penguin mm. I was figuring it being it.

Comment: @loan_2314 I'm a bit confused as to what you're saying, but if you disagree then that duplicate has nothing to do with commands, this is entirely different

Comment: @loan_2314 Please ensure you are checking duplicates based on the proposed duplicate's *answers*, not just the question or its title.

Answer (score 2):

To give a custom potion to a player you can use the command:

```
/give <selector> minecraft:potion{CustomPotionEffects:[{Id:<id>,Duration:<duration>}],Potion:"minecraft:water"}
```

Replace <selector> with whatever you are giving it to, <id> with the numerical ID for what you want, and <duration> with the duration in ticks.
[See here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Potion#ID) for a list of potion IDs.

If you want multiple effects on one potion you can duplicate `{Id:<id>,Duration:<duration>}` within its list multiple times, separated with commas.

Comment: The OP doesn't seem to understand what IDs are supposed to be and where. They're [here](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Effect) in the Effect IDs section.

Comment: Edited it and added link to answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're fine with using vanilla potions you can use this site to generate the command for you:
https://www.digminecraft.com/generators/give_potion.php